# Slack workspace bot to bot communication

Tags: api, integration, slack, slack-api

i am trying to send messages through Amazon alexa via a bot-user to an already created chat bot that is within the workspace already.

after using webhooks i realised the chatbot does not recognize the messages i am posting through my bot-user.

my problem solving attempts included:

using the "as_user" method set as true. so messages are sent by the user but it seems to only visually change the name of the bot-user and my chat bot still does not respond to my messages.

is it even possible for a bot-user using slack web API to communicate to an App-bot that is within a channel on a workspace? I am using Postman to test. i suspect it has something to do with he scopes of the bot-user and the chatbot within the workspace just not being able to see the bot-user scope. This is all within the slack web api and this is how i am communicating with the workspace through the bot user.

see images to illustrate.

thanks alot hope you can help! :)

First image of postman:

[image: First image of postman]

second image of slack intentions:

[image: second image of slack intentions]

Comment: do you want to send message to the other bot containing text or use slash commands?

Comment: i want to send messages so i can get a resposne from the chatbot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages from real users look slightly different then message from bots / apps.

Apparently your chatbot is ignoring messages that are not coming form a real user. So the only way to "fix" that would be to modify the chatbot logic.

Example for message from real user:

```
 {
      "type": "message",
      "user": "U12345467",
      "text": "Good read for some of guys",
      "ts": "1531745292.000021"
 }
```

Example for a bot message:

```
 {
      "text": "Hey guys",
      "bot_id": "B12345678",          
      "type": "message",
      "subtype": "bot_message",
      "ts": "1531700187.000049"
 }
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the response, what are you suggesting that i change here. do i make changes to the bot-user within my postman POST request or to my chatbot on the backend code of the chatbot that is within slack? thanks!